# How to Convert This Curl Request to Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, request

I'm using Streamlabs API to update loyalty points for users. After executing the below, points are not updated and an error is thrown to the catch block. The only example given for doing this request is with a curl request. (see [here](https://dev.streamlabs.com/v1.0/reference#pointsimport)). Maybe their example is wrong?

I'm using Javascript and the Request-Promise module. I've successfully done POST requests with this module for Oauth with Twitch. However I cannot get this post to Streamlabs API to work, I've tried a few ways. This is the same code I used for a POST request to the Twitch API and it was successful. I cannot figure out why it's not working for Streamlabs:

```
      const options = {
        access_token: streamlabsToken,
        channel: TWITCH_CHANNEL,
        users: 'users[' + username + ']=' + REFERRAL_POINTS
      }


      request.post(pointsAddEndpoint, { json: options })
        .then((slResponse) => {                                                       // Then 2
            if (slResponse.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
              console.log('Streamlabs response: ' + slResponse.message);
            }
            res.end();
        })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error adding refer points: ' + error.message);
        res.end();
      });
```

I'm sure I'm just formatting something wrong here, any input?

**UPDATE**

I got a curl request to work. The parameters for 'users' shouldn't be 'users=users[username]=20&users[username]=30' it should be just 'users[username]=20&users[username]=30' (removed the 'users=').

I did this in my `options` object like this:

```
      const options = {
        access_token: streamlabsToken,
        channel: TWITCH_CHANNEL
      }

      options['users[' + username + ']'] = REFERRAL_POINTS;
```

However this still doesn't work. I know I'm setting the 'users' param correctly because I printed to the log `options['users[' + username + ']']` and it gave me the correct REFERRAL_POINTS.

At this point I'm thinking I'll just type the whole thing out as a string. How do I pass that into the body of the `request.post`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out the API will not accept body parameters, even though the API reference says that's how you should do it. In fact they should be query parameters. I guess the API reference is incorrect. I added the params directly into the url, and put the Streamlabs OAuth access token in the header, then it worked!

```
      var dataString = 'users[' + username + ']=' + REFERRAL_POINTS + '&channel=' + TWITCH_CHANNEL;

      const options = {
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/points/add' + '?' + dataString,
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + streamlabsToken
          },
          json: true
      };


      request.post(options)
        .then((slResponse) => { 
          // Do something                                                      
        })
       .catch(function (error) {
          // Do something
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/points/add', // whatever the endpoint
    body: {
        access_token: streamlabsToken,
        channel: TWITCH_CHANNEL,
        users: 'users[' + username + ']=' + REFERRAL_POINTS
    },
    json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
};


request(options)
.then((parsedBody) => {
    // POST succeeded...
})
.catch((err) => {
    // POST failed...
});
```

Comment: See my update. Adding 'users' as a property is not how the API wants it, they want each user to be their own property. Hopefully it makes sense in my update.

Comment: I did also try this code (but changed the users parameter to users[username] like in my update). It works when hitting other endpoints like subtracting points from the user, but doesn’t work for adding points. It’s a real mystery because the curl equivalent of the code I’m using works just fine. But when I convert the curl command to JavaScript it’s doesn’t want to work.